# CompareValidator not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I would prefer to use an asp.net Validation Control as I currently have other Validation Controls within the same View. I need to error messages to be displayed wihtin a Validation Summary.

I have two textboxes and I need to make sure than textboxA is LessThan textboxB.

I have used the CompareValidator and have set the properties to:

- ControlToCompare: textboxB
- ControlToValidate: textboxA
- Operator: GreaterThan / Also tried LessThan
- Type: Date

Here is the problem:

- When I provide a time within textboxA
  and move onto textboxB the validation
  error is displayed. I thought my if
  statement would fix this but it
  doesn’t.

Within the Click Event for the 'Update' button I have added the following code, as I only need it to validate if both textboxA/textboxB != null.

```
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxB.Text))
        {
            Debug.Write("Valid");
            timeCompareValidator.IsValid = true;    
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Clare

Comment: Do you want to compare dates entered in textBoxA and TextBoxB on client side or on server side?

Comment: I think I need both. I have added the properties to the client side. But I am seeing whether it is validated on the serverside.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to compare two dates.

[I found this code on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx):

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 12, 0, 0);
int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
string relationship;

if (result < 0)
   relationship = "is earlier than";
else if (result == 0)
   relationship = "is the same time as";         
else
   relationship = "is later than";

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", date1, relationship, date2);
// The example displays the following output:
//    8/1/2009 12:00:00 AM is earlier than 8/1/2009 12:00:00 PM
```

Comment: I am comparing to times, however the closest type I found was 'Date'. Can this be to converted to use the CompareValidator?

Comment: I'm not familiar with CompareValidator, sorry.Could it be that it dose not recognize your input as a date?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to try changing your if statement to:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxA.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxB.text))
```

Comment: The same problem still happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare two dates or times on the server side use this solution

```
DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxA.Text);
DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBoxB.Text);

int result = dt1.CompareTo(dt2)
```

Comment: Would this be located within the - protected void checkTimes_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)?

Comment: Yes, but it's be better if you locate this on the ButtonClick

Comment: Where would the GreaterThan operator be located?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a CustomValidator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx(VS.71).aspx).
BTW: Why are you calling the validator directly?

```
timeCompareValidator.Validate();
```

Normally the Validators are evaluated during Page.Validate() which every Button fires (if CausesValidation is not set to false)

Comment: I worked through a example and this told me to call it directly.